# Stack implementation using a linked list

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list, stack

To understand the concept, I implemented the stack operations using a linked list. Please review the code and tell me your suggestions.

**Node.java**

```
public class Node {

public int data;
public Node next;

public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void displayNode() {
    System.out.print(data);
    System.out.print("  ");

 }
}
```

**LinkList.java**

```
public class LinkList {

private Node first = null;

public void insertFirst(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data);
    n.next = first;
    first = n;
}

public Node deleteFirst() {
    Node temp = first;
    first = first.next;
    return temp;
}

public void displayList() {
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        current.displayNode();
        current = current.next;
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (first == null);
  }
}
```

**LinkListStack.java**

```
public class LinkListStack {

LinkList li = new LinkList();

public void push(int data) {
    li.insertFirst(data);
}

public void pop() {
    while(!li.isEmpty()){
    li.deleteFirst();
    }
}

public void displayStack() {
    System.out.println("  ");
    li.displayList();
  }
}
```

**LinkListStackDemo.java**

```
public class LinkListStackDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkListStack st = new LinkListStack();

    st.push(50);
    st.push(70);
    st.push(190);
    st.displayStack();
    st.pop();
    st.displayStack();

  }
 }
```

Comment: Please do not change the while condition to an if-condition in your edits, these have been addressed in answers. [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Time complexity

The time complexity of push and pop operations should be \$O(1)\$, and so it is in your case too. It doesn't matter how many elements you have, these operations should take constant time. *(UPDATE: you've edited your original post, and made `pop` wipe out the entire stack. That's not normal! Normally, the `pop` operation on a stack should return the most recently added value. That's \$O(1)\$ time.)*

#### Avoid printing to `stdout`

Instead of the `display*` methods that print to `stdout`, it would be better to override `toString`. That way your implementation would be more testable.

#### Generalize

Why limit the stack, linked list, node elements to `int` type? It would be trivially easy to rewrite to make it work with any type `T`.

*The question is tagged "beginner", so I understand you might not be familiar with generics just yet. In that case, see [this official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html). Or perhaps you can also learn from my example implementation further down.*

#### Add an `isEmpty` method for the stack

Your linked list has an `isEmpty` method but the stack doesn't. It would be good to have such method for the stack too.

#### Reinventing the wheel

When reinventing the wheel (here, linked list), it's good to mimic what exists. For example, `java.util.LinkedList` uses the method names `addFirst` and `removeFirst`, instead of `insertFirst` and `deleteFirst`. It's good to follow the example.

#### Access modifiers and encapsulation

As @rolfl pointed out, `Node` should not be exposed to the outside. Users of the stack should not have to know its inner workings.

Also, the members of `Node` should be private, and the `data` and `next` fields can be `final`. Similarly in the stack, the linked list member should be private.

#### Naming

You use poor names in many places.

- Instead of `n` for the new node when replacing the first item of a linked list, `newFirst` would be more intuitive
- Instead of `temp` for the old first item removed from a linked list, `oldFirst` would be more intuitive
- Instead of `li` for the linked list in the stack, `linkedList` would be more intuitive

#### Suggested implementation

```
class LinkList<T> {

    private static class Node<T> {

        private final T data;
        private final Node<T> next;

        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }

    private Node<T> first = null;

    public void addFirst(T data) {
        Node<T> newFirst = new Node<T>(data);
        newFirst.next = first;
        first = newFirst;
    }

    public T removeFirst() {
        Node<T> oldFirst = first;
        first = first.next;
        return oldFirst.data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            builder.append(current).append(" ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

}

class LinkListStack<T> {

    private final LinkList<T> linkedList = new LinkList<>();

    public void push(T data) {
        linkedList.addFirst(data);
    }

    public T pop() {
        return linkedList.removeFirst();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return linkedList.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return linkedList.toString();
    }
}
```

#### Unit tests

```
@Test
public void testPushAndPop() {
    LinkListStack<Integer> st = new LinkListStack<>();
    st.push(50);
    st.push(70);
    st.push(190);
    assertEquals("190 70 50", st.toString());
    assertEquals(190, (int) st.pop());
    assertEquals("70 50", st.toString());
}

@Test
public void testPopUntilEmpty() {
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(50, 70, 190, 20);
    LinkListStack<Integer> st = new LinkListStack<>();
    assertTrue(st.isEmpty());
    for (Integer value : values) {
        st.push(value);
    }
    assertFalse(st.isEmpty());
    for (int i = values.size(); i > 0; --i) {
        assertEquals(values.get(i - 1), st.pop());
    }
    assertTrue(st.isEmpty());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, there are a few things to go through here.

### Node

Starting with the Node class. This should not be public. There is no reason for you to expose the logic to anything other than the LinkedList class. It is common to include the Node class as a static inner class of the data structure. Something like:

```
public class LinkList {

    private static class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        void displayNode() {
            System.out.print(data);
            System.out.print("  ");

        }

    }

    private Node first = null;

    ...
```

### Complexity

You assert that the complexities for the push and pop are \$O(n)\$, but this is not true. Both of these operations affect only the head of the list, e.g.:

> ```
> public void insertFirst(int data) {
>     Node n = new Node(data);
>     n.next = first;
>     first = n;
> }
> ```

As a consequence, they are \$O(1)\$ operations, and that is what I would expect for a linked list insert-at-the-head.

### LinkedList

The deleteFirst method should not return a Node value. It should be the 'mirror image' of the insert method. The insert method inserts an `int`, and the delete method should return an `int` as well.

### LinkedListStack

`pop()` methods should return the popped value. Yours returns nothing, it's void. It is not normal.

***Note:*** **it has been pointed out that your pop method removes all values from the list because of the `while (!isEmpty())` loop. This loop was added [after I wrote this part of the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/62710/revisions) (but before I pressed 'submit'). The sentence I have above is accurate for a classic 'pop' method, which removes the first value from the stack (and in Java, and many other languages, returns that value too).**

**What you have now is worse, you have a method called 'pop' which does nothing of the sort, it is a 'clear' method, it empties the stack. As a result, you do not have a stack at all, you have a class called a Stack that is not a Stack. Additionally, it is in many cases WOM (Write Only Memory), you can write values to the Stack, but never read them.**

### Summary

Your indentation is off. I presume this is because you are not familiar with Code Review's markdown system. You should paste your code in to the edit box, then select it all, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: `pop()` returning nothing is not normal in Java particularly, you mean?  In C++, it is normal.

Comment: @Jamal Maybe because C++ tries to save every fraction of nanosecond which returning an unused value could cost. Actually, it could be costly if a big object was to be copied and the compiler isn't guaranteed to see it can omit it. This can't happen in Java. That said, it's sad that Java Collection aren't more STL inspired.

Comment: Note that pop() is a while loop; not only does it not return anything, but it destroys the entire stack.

Comment: @raptortech97 - you're right, but [it was not when I first answered the question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/62710/1).... but, I see that he got his edit in just before I got my answer in, so, I guess we can let it stand.

Comment: @raptortech97 - this makes the problem even worse, I have added a note in my answer.

Comment: @maaartinus - the reason that `pop` does not return an object in C++ is that returning an object copies it, and copying can throw an exception. If that happens, the object has been lost.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thx, this makes sense. So the poorgrammers are supposed to do `top` first, right? But when an exception gets throws in `top`, what should I do?

Comment: @maaartinus - yes, call `top` to get the object. `top` won't throw an exception: it returns a reference. If you copy that object and the copy throws an exception the stack is still intact, so you haven't lost anything. Worst case you call `pop` to get rid of the troublemaker.

Comment: @maaartinus - no need for derogatory statements. There are many that could be made about Java as well, but that's not productive nor appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you write

```
public void pop() {
    while(!li.isEmpty()){
    li.deleteFirst();
    }
}
```

instead of

```
public void pop() {
    if(!li.isEmpty()){
    li.deleteFirst();
    }
}
```

because the you wrote it, `pop()` would pop all of the elements off the stack, instead of one. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: This is not really an answer. In fact it has a question at the end. Please amend this to more closely follow the structure of an answer.