# Array Implementation of Stack

Tags: java, beginner, stack

I've implemented the basic logic of a stack data structure. How can I make this code more generic? Is there any better way to display the stack contents?

**StackMethods.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackMethods {
    private int top;
    int size;
    int[] stack ;

    public StackMethods(int arraySize){
        size=arraySize;
        stack= new int[size];
        top=-1;
    }

    public void push(int value){
        if(top==size-1){
            System.out.println("Stack is full, can't push a value");
        }
        else{

            top=top+1;
            stack[top]=value;
        }
    }

    public void pop(){
        if(!isEmpty())
            top=top-1;
        else{
            System.out.println("Can't pop...stack is empty");
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return top==-1;
    }

    public void display(){

        for(int i=0;i<=top;i++){
            System.out.print(stack[i]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**StackReviseDemo.java**

```
public class StackReviseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackMethods newStack = new StackMethods(5);
        newStack.push(10);
        newStack.push(1);
        newStack.push(50);
        newStack.push(20);
        newStack.push(90);

        newStack.display();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be something returned by a call to `pop()` ? Also  calling the constructor with `-1` will blow up your class.

Comment: Great point... I really forgot about these cases.

Comment: @Heslacher - Arun has asked a similar question before, and recieved similar feedback about [pop not returning a value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62712/31503)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Good**

- Naming of parameters and methods follow the naming convention

**Bad**

- not checking input parameter for constructor
- **not listening to previous answers ( `pop()` returning nothing )**
- not using braces `{}` for every `if..else` statement

**Additional**

- `int size` should be `final` as it won't be changed.
- Instead of `display()` you can override `toString()` as this is more common.
- Instead of writing to `System.out` you should throw an exception.
- give your variables some space to breathe. E.g `top=top+1;` would be more readable if written like so `top = top + 1;`

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry for not listening to previous answers. I won't repeat the same.

Comment: The points you mention it is really required for writing a minimal optimized code and it means a lot in an enterprise application.

Answer (score 3):

Few comments:

- The name `StackMethods` is not the best name for this, you should rather pick a name that describes your entity, eg: `Stack`
- Your class only works for integers, where Stack is an `ADT` that should accept various types, so consider using `generics` instead

  ```
  class Stack<T>{
   private T[] stackArray;
  }
  ```
- the fields : `size`, and `stack` have `package access`, and this means classes within the same package can modify them, declare them as `private` instead.
- You should throw an unchecked exception in `push` method if the stack is full rather than printing something to the console

Comment: When I change my code to generic type, its showing error in array declaration :
stack=new int[size];   
How to fix this?

Comment: @ArunPrakash because it is not an int anymore, T[] array =(T[])new Object[length];

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an LinkedList inside of your `StackMethods.java`. It already has methods for to push and pop.

A simple example, without your size-limits, etc.:

```
public class StackReviseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> newStack = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        newStack.push(10);
        newStack.push(1);
        newStack.push(50);
        newStack.push(20);
        newStack.push(90);

        display(newStack);
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        newStack.pop();
        display(newStack);

    }

    private static void display(LinkedList<Integer> newStack) {
        boolean first = true;
        LinkedList<Integer> reversedStack = new LinkedList<>(newStack);
        Collections.reverse(reversedStack);
        for (Integer integer : reversedStack) {
            if (first) first = false;
            else System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(integer);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: While `LinkedList` already has methods to implement a stack, OP is apparently a beginner and using such methods doesn't teach very much about how the concept of a stack works. Also, `LinkedList` will grow to arbitrary size (computer memory allowing), while the OP's stack implementation specifically has limited size. You can argue growth is better, but it's definitely different functionality and the OP's version isn't _wrong_.

Comment: Every computer science should be writing ADTs from scratch rather than using existing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

@Heslacher's and @Sleiman Jneidi's answers are really good. Just in case you want to have a list implementation, you can compose List inside your custom-defined Stack ADT. This way, only stack methods will be exposed outside, excluding that of List's.

```
public class Stack<T> {

     private List<T> contents;

     public Stack() {
             contents = new ArrayList<>();
     }

     public void push(T item) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException{
          contents.add(item); //add to tail
     }

     public T pop() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
          return contents.remove(contents.size() - 1); //remove from tail
     }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
            return contents.toString();
      }
}
```